# How to make the text in the tab bar to show in a same line?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I was trying to clone an app named stucor but the tab bar in that app is different, when i tried to implement in flutter all the texts in the tab bar were of the same size and the text in it were in many lines like[image]

So, i tried wrapping the texts in FittedBox widget but then the font size got reduced as seen in the above image. What i am trying to achieve is
[image]

````
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 7,
          child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          bottom: TabBar(
            tabs: [

              Tab(child: FittedBox(child: Text('HOME', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),)) ),
              Tab(child: Text('RESULTS', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),) ),
              Tab(child: Text('INTERNALS', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),) ),
              Tab(child: Text('NOTES', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),) ),
              Tab(child: Text('EVENTS', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),) ),
              Tab(child: Text('QUESTION PAPERS', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),) ),
              Tab(child: Text('JOBS', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),) )]),```
````

Comment: Share the tabbar code..

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: I have edited the question

Comment: Set the `isScrollable` property of the `TabBar` to `true`. @PurushothamanU

Comment: Added an answer just so others can see incase they come across a similar issue. @PurushothamanU.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, you can acheive the `TabBar` behaviour by setting the `isScrollable` property of the `TabBar` to `true`.

**Posting it as an answer here so other can see:**

I added an example using your widget tree:

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 7,
          child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          bottom: TabBar(
            isScrollable: true, // new line
            tabs: [

              Tab(child: FittedBox(child: Text('HOME', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),)) ),
              Tab(child: Text('RESULTS', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),) ),
              Tab(child: Text('INTERNALS', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),) ),
              Tab(child: Text('NOTES', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),) ),
              Tab(child: Text('EVENTS', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),) ),
              Tab(child: Text('QUESTION PAPERS', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),) ),
              Tab(child: Text('JOBS', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),) )]),
```